# How do I tell CPAN.pm to install all modules in a specific directory?

Tags: perl, cpan

I have set

```
makepl_arg         [INSTALLDIRS=site PREFIX=~/perl]
mbuildpl_arg       [--install_base ~/perl]
```

in the CPAN.pm configuration.  I had hoped that this would cause modules to get installed in the same place, but I still have to set multiple paths in PERL5LIB:

```
export PERL5LIB=~/perl/share/perl/5.10.0:~/perl/lib/perl5/:~/perl/lib/perl/5.10.0
```

This has been the case for a long time and I have just lived with it, but I was wondering if anyone knew how to get CPAN.pm to put all modules in the same directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib).  It will handle all the configuration for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using INSTALL_BASE for both? You have to set multiple directories because you're telling CPAN.pm to install in multiple directories. Tell it to install everything in the same place:

```
makepl_arg         [INSTALL_BASE=~/perl]
mbuildpl_arg       [--install_base ~/perl]
```

Comment: Make sure you have a relatively recent ExtUtils::MakeMaker.