# How can I tell Module::Build not to add the lib/perl5 subdirectories to the installation path?

Tags: perl, installation, module

I am trying to setup a directory that contains Perl modules that should be set aside to not interfere with a production system.

This works OK, with modules that use [`Module::Install`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Install). I just specify a "`lib`" option and all is well. Now I tried and tried and I simply cannot make this happen with [`Module::Build`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Build). For instance, this command:

```
./Build install --lib /foo
```

Will install the module in "`/foo/share/perl/5.10.0`".

How can I get rid off the "`share/perl/5.10.0`" part?

PS: Yes, I have taken a long look at the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Build) and found some promising sections, but I simply must admit that I seem to be too stupid to grok them.

Comment: Would `local::lib` do the trick? See this question and its answer. (I'm not quite sure it's the same issue, but it may help). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786544/how-do-i-tell-cpan-pm-to-install-all-modules-in-a-specific-directory

Comment: I guess it would or could do the trick, but it feels like a kludge and I'd rather try to tweak Module::Build first before I try my luck mit local::lib.

Comment: Now I'm curious more generally: what do you see as the advantage to putting all the libs in one basket (a la Sinan's answer)? Even without this, since all modules would be installed at `/foo/something`, they would still be out of the way of the production system's default libraries, wouldn't they? Unless I'm confused, all you're doing is cutting down on the depth of the `/foo` directory.

Comment: Most of the modules I need are already where I'd like them to be. I'd have to reinstall those or use two addiditional module paths.

Comment: Is it really worth your time to care about an extra lib/perl5? You're looking to do a lot of extra work to get something that most people won't expect and for no additional benefit. Give in and move on in life to something more important :)

Comment: Oh, come on. 10 minutes ain't that bad. God knows how often I will have to type that "lib/perl5" string, which in reality, will be a lot longer (sun-solaris/perl5/lib/5.8.8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`install_path`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Module::Build#INSTALL_PATHS). It looks like (I haven't tried) you can either put in `.modulebuildrc` or specify on the command line all of the path options:

```
./Build install --install_base $CUSTOMPERLSTUFF \
                --install_path lib=$CUSTOMPERLSTUFF/lib \
                --install_path arch=$CUSTOMPERLSTUFF/lib
```

Comment: That did the trick! I really needed to provide all three arguments and I'm still not sure how you were able to distill that out of the documentation. But it works! Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to make this the default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best chance is with [`install_base`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Module::Build#install_base). From the doc:

> #### `install_base`
>
> You can also set the whole bunch of installation paths by supplying the `install_base` parameter to point to a directory on your system. For instance, if you set `install_base` to "`/home/ken`" on a Linux system, you'll install as follows:
>
> ```
>   lib     => /home/ken/lib/perl5
>   arch    => /home/ken/lib/perl5/i386-linux
>   script  => /home/ken/bin
>   bin     => /home/ken/bin
>   bindoc  => /home/ken/man/man1
>   libdoc  => /home/ken/man/man3
>   binhtml => /home/ken/html
>   libhtml => /home/ken/html
> ```

Comment: Yes, but this is exactly what I **not** want. No "lib/perl5" for me, please.

Comment: You should change what you want, then. Distributions may install other things too, so there might be a bin directory, etc.