# Why does installing certain CPAN modules require root privilege?

Tags: perl, cpan

I need to install some CPAN modules in a linux box which I do not have the root privilege.

The installation of [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) goes quite smoothly. But the try to install [`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Find::Rule) failed with warning  "you do not have permissions to install into ....." and hint "you may have to su to root to install the package"

I'm puzzled why some CPAN module installation require root privilege while there are others do not ? and If I  really want to use the [`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Find::Rule) in that linux box , is there any work-around solution I can choose ?

thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you setup `CPAN` for that user to install into a directory you control?

If so, then you could be running in the differences amongst modules that use [`Extutils::MakeMaker`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Extutils::MakeMaker) (the oldest and most common build/install system), [`Module::Build`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Module::Build), and [`Module::Install`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Module::Install).  They all have little quirks.

This is why [`local::lib`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/local::lib) was created.  Once you have it installed and setup you shouldn't have to worry about it again (except for rogue modules that want to write things to specific places even though they have been told not to).

Comment: To elucidate, the build mechanisms can all install to local directories (that you own) rather than system directories (that are read-only because they affect all users) but the mechanisms of making them install in the new place differ.  local::lib knows how to handle them all, and, as an added bonus, updates your Perl include path.

Comment: And your executable path so you can find the scripts that some modules (like Perl::Tidy) install.

Answer (score 9):

Check out [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib) for installing to other locations.

Answer (score 8):

From [perlfaq8](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html):

---

[How do I keep my own module/library directory?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_keep_my_own)

When you build modules, tell Perl where to install the modules.

For Makefile.PL-based distributions, use the INSTALL_BASE option when generating Makefiles:

```
perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/mydir/perl
```

You can set this in your CPAN.pm configuration so modules automatically install in your private library directory when you use the CPAN.pm shell:

```
% cpan
cpan> o conf makepl_arg INSTALL_BASE=/mydir/perl
cpan> o conf commit
```

For Build.PL-based distributions, use the --install_base option:

```
perl Build.PL --install_base /mydir/perl
```

You can configure CPAN.pm to automatically use this option too:

```
% cpan
cpan> o conf mbuild_arg --install_base /mydir/perl
cpan> o conf commit
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have permissions to install your module to a system directory like `/usr/lib`. If you want to do this, you need to run the `make install` step with superuser permissions (`su` or `sudo`).

Alternatively, you can install a Perl module to a local directory which you have permissions for, rather than installing to the default system location. You specify the custom directory when generating the makefile.

From [perlmodinstall](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.0/pod/perlmodinstall.pod):

```
gzip -dc yourmodule.tar.gz | tar -xof -
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/my/perl_directory
make
make test
make install
```

Comment: perlmodinstall is old (and now it's on my list of things to fix). Instead of PREFIX, use INSTALL_BASE.

Comment: And, this is a work intensive way to go about it since it doesn't handle dependencies for you. Just use `cpan .` to install from the current directory, including all of the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that some packages under UNIX require the user to be "root". When installing *Template::Toolkit* it triggered *AppConfig*, which bailed out with:

```
  You may have to su to root to install the package
  (Or you may want to run something like
    o conf make_install_make_command 'sudo make'
  to raise your permissions.
```

Cygwin is not UNIX. It is just a set of UNIX utilities for Cygwin. There is no *root* user and no *sudo* and no way to fake it. If you run Bash as administrator this has not the effect of somehow becoming *root*. (Actually it can be dangerous.)

The actual problem was that */usr/man/man3* had no permissions:

```
 > ls -ls /usr/share/man
total 1.2M
384K d--------- 1 spindlea Domain Users 0 Oct 29 18:55 man1/
768K d--------- 1 spindlea Domain Users 0 Oct 29 18:55 man3/
8.0K d--------- 1 spindlea Domain Users 0 Oct 29 12:35 man5/
 12K d--------- 1 spindlea Domain Users 0 Oct  6 16:26 man7/
 12K d--------- 1 spindlea Domain Users 0 Oct 29 12:35 man8/
   0 d--------- 1 spindlea Domain Users 0 Oct  6 16:26 mann/
```

So the man-pages could not be installed. Reason: *C:/Cygwin* was unpacked from an archive. Under NTFS file systems, Cygwin by default implements UNIX permissions on Windows ACLs (although you can't see them in the "Security" tab). These did not survive the ZIP archive.

To restore the permissions use something like:

```
 > chmod -R 755 /usr/bin        # sets -rwxr-xr-x
 > chmod -R 755 /usr/local/bin  # sets -rwxr-xr-x
 > find /bin  -type d -print -exec chmod 777 {} \;
 > find /etc  -type d -print -exec chmod 777 {} \;
 > find /usr  -type d -print -exec chmod 777 {} \;
     .
     .
```

Problem gone. The installation went through without problems. CPAN was able to satisfy all dependencies.

No "You may have to su to root to install the package" errors anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Possible other answers already on Stackoverflow:

- [How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory)
- [How do I tell CPAN.pm to install all modules in a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786544/how-do-i-tell-cpan-pm-to-install-all-modules-in-a-specific-directory)
- [How can I install CPAN modules locally without root access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102850/how-can-i-install-cpan-modules-locally-without-root-access-dynaloader-pm-line-22)

Answer (score -3):

It's because some packages are installed into locations that your user doesn't have permission to write to.

My recommendation would be to get an admin to install the packages for you. I suspect there isn't a simple way to work around this.

Comment: @Gordon : is there any rule that guide the module writer where should a module be depolyed and is there any flexibity that the user can choose where a module be installed ?

Comment: sorry, it's not something i've ever tried. If it fails for that reason I just install it using sudo

Comment: There are simple work-arounds. That is likely why this answer has been down-voted.